# A Database Error Occurred and A PHP Error was encountered Message: Array to string conversion in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, codeigniter

I'm new in php, I'm trying to make application online shop with codeigniter but I've got some error.

**First Error**

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>   Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\kocart\system\database\DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 124

this is some code from DB_driver.php

```
if ( ! $this->conn_id)
    {
        log_message('error', 'Unable to connect to the database');

        if ($this->db_debug)
        {
            $this->display_error('db_unable_to_connect');
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Line Number 124 is

```
$this->display_error('db_unable_to_connect');
```

but I try change code in `application\config\database.php` from

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

to

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
```

A Database Error occurred is solved but get another error

**Second Error**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Array to string conversion
>   Filename: core/Lang.php
>   Line Number: 100

---

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Array to string conversion
>   Filename: core/Lang.php
>   Line Number: 100

---

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Array to string conversion
>   Filename: core/Lang.php
>   Line Number: 110

this is some code from core\Lang.php

```
foreach (get_instance()->load->get_package_paths(TRUE) as $package_path)
        {
            if (file_exists($package_path.'language/'.$idiom.'/'.$langfile))
            {
                include($package_path.'language/'.$idiom.'/'.$langfile);
                $found = TRUE;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($found !== TRUE)
        {
            show_error('Unable to load the requested language file: language/'.$idiom.'/'.$langfile);
        }
    }
```

Line Number 100 is

```
if (file_exists($package_path.'language/'.$idiom.'/'.$langfile))
```

and Line Number 110 is

```
show_error('Unable to load the requested language file: language/'.$idiom.'/'.$langfile);
```

---

> An Error Was Encountered
>   Unable to load the requested language file: language/Array/home_lang.php

and this is some code from language\Array\home_lang.php

```
<?php
$lang['currency'] = "Currency";
$lang['language'] = "Language";
$lang['best_sell'] = "The Best-Selling Products";
$lang['add_basket'] = "Add Basket";
$lang['reviews'] = "reviews";
$lang['most_popular'] = "The Most Popular Products";
$lang['delete'] = "Delete";
$lang['update_cart'] = "Update your Cart";
$lang['total'] = "Total";
$lang['view_basket'] = "View Basket";
```

Comment: I'm sorry, does this translate to "I turned off the error message and now I'm getting other errors?" Check your credentials. Ensure you can connect using them by employing other tools first.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @tadman yeah... something like that, i'm new in PHP and i dont understand what happened to tihs code...

Comment: I think you are unnecessary searching in core files. Please update your code which you want to execute. May be you are echoing something which is of type Array.